# Create option by data-atribute with jquery without repeating

Tags: jquery, html

Good evening folks.
Ok, so I have this `<li>` with some `data-attribute`s, like

```
<li class="mix evento" data-mes="jan">
```

I need to fetch all `data-mes` from all the li's on this page, and add'em to a select>option, but without repeating them (`data-mes` is basically `data-month`, and each li represents an Event with some date).

That will be used to filter the Li's using the beautifull [MixitUp Plugin](http://mixitup.io/) by month (`data-mes`)

Well, I know that, to get 1 data-attribute i should do something like

```
var month = $('#ulID li').data('mes');
```

But I have no idea how to fech them into an array and how to make sure they not repeat if happen more than one time. Any help is much appreciated..

*Edit: working code here http://bit.ly/16xI0yV click the white buttons aside of 'ordenar' to test the sorting functionallity*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/gs7S3/). All lines are explained through comments below.

```
// gets all `data-mes` into an array
var months = $('#ulID li').map(function() { return $(this).data('mes'); }).get();
// remove repeated meses
months = months.filter(function(e, p) { return months.indexOf(e) == p; });

// sorts the months
var order = ['jan','fev','mar','abr','mai','jun','jul','ago','set','out','nov','dez'];
orderedMonths = months.sort(function(a,b){ return order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b); });

// add them, ordered, to the <select> with id #selectMes
$.each(orderedMonths, function(_, v) {
    $('#selectMes').append($('<option>').val(v).text(v));
});
```

Comment: `.unique()` only works on an array of dom elements - from docs `Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.`

Comment: Hey, @acdcjunior , how would I change the months.sort() function to sort by number? valeu mano rs

Comment: Hey, there! What number? `data-mes` is the number? eh nois! :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
<ul id="ulID">
    <li class="mix evento" data-mes="jan">Jan</li>
    <li class="mix evento" data-mes="feb">Feb</li>
    <!-- etc... -->
</ul>
<select></select>
```

JS:

```
var months = [], $select = $('select');
$('#ulID li').each(function () {
    var mes = $(this).data('mes');
    if ($.inArray(mes, months) === -1) {
        months.push(mes);
        $select.append('<option value="'+mes+'">'+mes+'</option>');
    }
});
```

This loops through all the `li`s and checks their `data-mes` attribute. Every time a new value comes up it's added to the `months` array. Every value is checked against this array to make sure the same value isn't processed twice.

If the value is unique then an extra option is added to the select menu.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/cns3b/